# execution of npx --watch command in shell terminal: permission denied?

Tags: shell, npm, tailwind-css, permission-denied, npx

I've started using macOS recently and I've encountered a problem when trying to execute my `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/CSS/input.css -o ./src/CSS/output.css --watch` command for my TailwindCSS project originally created on my Windows PC. When executing the command, the terminal responds by `sh: /Users/gregory.buffard/Documents/GitHub/2022-portfolio/node_modules/.bin/tailwindcss: Permission denied`. As my first reaction I've tried to execute it again with a `sudo` at the beginning of the command, but the same issue occurs again after entering the sudo password. I also checked if my account in the computer has admin privileges, and yes it does, so I cannot determine why I do not have permission for such command.

For more context - the css files which I try to `--watch` in the command above, are located in a folder "CSS", which is located in the "src" folder, which is located in the root folder of the project. Also the "node_modules" folder is located in the root folder.

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: Try `chmod a+x` on the offending file.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions, unfortunately it didn't helped on its own, but you have reminded me of trying to adjust the permission for the file using the 777 code. So thank you very much!

Comment: Try deleting the ```node_modules``` folder and run ```npm i```; worked for me.